# How to make a new line in div displayed as table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have this HTML Markup:

```
<div style="display:table;">
    <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"></span>
    <a style="display:table-cell;"><span></span></a>
    <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"></span>
</div>
```

All what I want is that my last span should be shown on a new line.

Comment: Would using `<p>` suffice?

Comment: Use <br/> before span.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap it on  a new line, set it as a **p** tag:

```
   <div style="display:table;">
        <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"></span>
        <a style="display:table-cell;"><span></span></a>
        <p style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"></p>
    </div
```

Alternatively use a **br** tag:

```
   <div style="display:table;">
        <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"></span>
        <a style="display:table-cell;"><span></span></a>
        <br>
        <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"></span>
    </div
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.**And remove display:table-cell from the parent div**.

```html
<div>
  <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">First</span>
  <a style="display:table-cell;"><span>Second span</span></a>
  <br />
  <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">child</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `display:table` so all its member are display in cell

so you want last span in new line you will remove `table` from div and simply display it

```html
<div>
  <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">1</span>
  <a style="display:table-cell;"><span>2</span></a>
  <br />
  <span style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">3</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use those inline-styles, you can still target the last span with css but you have to use !important.

```
div > span:last-of-type {
  display:table-row!important;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/4re7zdku/)